# Windows - Adding Directory with Subdirectories to left navigation pane

Tags: c#, windows, registry, sidebar

I want to add a directory node to the left navigation pane. It should contain links to subdirectories that are actually on the file system. Currenty it just displays the contents of the last registered path under "Test".
I illustrated the problem: Left side is current state. Right side (photomontage) is how I expect it.
[image: f]

Is this possible or do I have to link to a directory where I add symlinks to my target directories?

That's what I have done so far (basically from a similar SO question and the "Integrate a Cloud Storage Provider" Windows help Page):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] defaultFolders = { "C:\\Intel\\Logs", "C:\\Python27" };
            var sm = new ShellextensionManger();
            var guid = Guid.Parse("{03d6d437-c11c-49fc-9dcd-aa65e15b77ea}");
            sm.createShellFolder(guid.ToString(), "Test", defaultFolders, "C:\\icon.ico");
            sm.removeShellFolder(guid.ToString());
        }
    }

internal class ShellextensionManger
    {
        private const uint SORT_ORDER_VERY_TOP = 1;

        public ShellextensionManger() {}

        public void createShellFolder(string strGUID, string strFolderTitle, IEnumerable<string> strTargetFolderPaths, string strIconPath)
        {
            RegistryKey localKey, keyTemp, rootKey;
            localKey = getRegistryKeyArcgIndependent(RegistryHive.CurrentUser);

            // Add your CLSID and name your extension
            rootKey = localKey.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Classes\CLSID\{" + strGUID + "}");
            rootKey.SetValue("", strFolderTitle, RegistryValueKind.String);
            // Add your extension to the Navigation Pane and make it visible
            rootKey.SetValue("System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree", unchecked((int)0x1), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            // Set the location for your extension in the Navigation Pane
            rootKey.SetValue("SortOrderIndex", unchecked((int) SORT_ORDER_VERY_TOP), RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            // Set the image for your icon
            keyTemp = rootKey.CreateSubKey(@"DefaultIcon");
            keyTemp.SetValue("", strIconPath, RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
            keyTemp.Close();

            // Provide the dll that hosts your extension.
            keyTemp = rootKey.CreateSubKey(@"InProcServer32");
            keyTemp.SetValue("", @"%systemroot%\system32\shell32.dll", RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
            keyTemp.Close();

            /*
             * Define the instance object
             * Indicate that your namespace extension should function like other file folder structures in File Explorer. For more information about shell instance objects, see Creating Shell Extensions with Shell Instance Objects.
             */
            keyTemp = rootKey.CreateSubKey(@"Instance");
            keyTemp.SetValue("CLSID", "{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}", RegistryValueKind.String);
            keyTemp.Close();


            foreach (String path in strTargetFolderPaths) {
                keyTemp = rootKey.CreateSubKey(@"Instance\InitPropertyBag");
                // Provide the file system attributes of the target folder
                keyTemp.SetValue("Attributes", unchecked((int) (FileAttributes.Directory & FileAttributes.ReadOnly)), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                // Set the path for the sync root
                keyTemp.SetValue("TargetFolderPath", path, RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
                keyTemp.Close();
            }

            // Set appropriate shell flags
            keyTemp = rootKey.CreateSubKey(@"ShellFolder");
            keyTemp.SetValue("FolderValueFlags", unchecked((int)0x28), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            // Set the appropriate flags to control your shell behavior
            keyTemp.SetValue("Attributes", unchecked((int)0xF080004D), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            keyTemp.Close();
            rootKey.Close();

            // Register your extension in the namespace root
            keyTemp = localKey.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{" + strGUID + "}");
            keyTemp.SetValue("", strFolderTitle, RegistryValueKind.String);
            keyTemp.Close();

            // Hide your extension from the Desktop
            keyTemp = localKey.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel");
            keyTemp.SetValue("{" + strGUID + "}", unchecked((int)0x1), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            keyTemp.Close();
        }

        public void removeShellFolder(string strGUID)
        {
            RegistryKey localKey;
            localKey = getRegistryKeyArcgIndependent(RegistryHive.CurrentUser);

            localKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(@"Software\Classes\CLSID\{" + strGUID + "}", false);
            localKey.DeleteSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{" + strGUID + "}", false);
            localKey.DeleteSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel", false);
        }

        private RegistryKey getRegistryKeyArcgIndependent(RegistryHive registryHive) {
            RegistryView registryView = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
            return RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, registryView);
        }
    }
```

Please note that I remove that entry at the end of the main for debugging purpose. Set a breakpoint if you try the code.

Comment: Try your code and feedback the result and your issues, so we can help you.

Comment: I explained the behaviour of the code I adapted/wrote/executed of course. I also explained what I want to do with an illustration. The problem is that I don't know if and how nested entries are supported as it's meant primary for a directory tree (but maybe there is a hack one can archive this behaviour - but that's what I'm asking for). What else do you want me to do?

Comment: You add random GUID for a class in Registry. GUID should be a specific GUID for COM component.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I changed this. But I don't think it's related to the actual problem.

Comment: if you want to Integrate a Cloud Storage Provider, what provider you use?

Comment: I want to add custom folders there. I don't want to integrate a cloud storage provider. I used this help page as it's suggested documentation on how to register something in the navigation pane.